# R script, how do i assign 3 values from a collection with the same label to sort into levels

Tags: r

I am trying to do something like this, I want every name inside of england to be set to england so when it is ran it will count everything in that collection and they will all be added to englands total. as you can see below there are 9 other labels I want anything named as such to become another england label. I hope this makes sense to someone out there, I really didn't know how to explain this.

```
    area_c <- factor(Outlets2016_local$Region,levels = c("England","Scotland","Wales"),labels = c("England" = england,"Scotland","Wales"))
```

here is englands collection:

```
    england <- c("London","North East","East of England","West Midlands","South East","North West","East Midlands","South West","Yorkshire and The Humber")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following if you don't mind recoding **Outlets2016_local$Region**.

```
england <- c("London", "North East", "East of England", "West Midlands", "South East", "North West", "East Midlands", "South West", "Yorkshire and The Humber")   

Outlets2016_local$Region[Outlets2016_local$Region %in% england] <- "England"

area_c <- factor(Outlets2016_local$Region, levels = c("England", "Scotland", "Wales"), labels = c("England", "Scotland", "Wales"))
```

Comment: i was a bit too hasty wiht accepting the answer, i didn't quite understand the code but it worked so i thought it was fine however i've now noticed it modifies the database and just replaces regions entries with england. i was hoping to keep the original 9 region names in the region column and then have a seprate column with the area.

Comment: If you want to keep the original regions, just can create a new column:
`Outlets2016_local$RecodedRegion[Outlets2016_local$Region %in% england] <- "England"`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)